# Guest zone in D-Link DIR-615 wireless router

Tags: wireless-router

I have D Link DIR-615 wireless router. In my home network, I have MyBook fileserver and my pcs and mac, iphones etc. 
Is it possible to configure the router so that guests do not have access to my shared resources.

I do not know if it is possible easily, But I am agree to have some restriction on my part,
- Enable DHCP for guests but not for my devices  OR
- make subnet addresses for my devices and a different for dhcp  and then if there is any option to restrict access between subnets etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Dir-615 doesn't have the capability of Guest Zone like the Dir-655. But you can create a virtual interface and bridge two subnets to separate traffic and secure the network.

This is a good tutorial if your router supports DD-wrt.

http://shitepod.co.uk/dd-wrt-multiple-wlan-set-up-on-a-dlink-dir-615/

Comment: So, the DIR-615 does support DD-WRT? your answer currently sounds like a question *"if your router supports DD-wrt"*

Comment: @Xen2050 All DIR-615 routers since hardware revision C1 are supported by DD-WRT https://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database